# Is it safe to use extract( $_REQUEST, EXTR_IF_EXISTS )?

Tags: php, security, extract

Within a function (not a class method), is it safe to use `extract( $_REQUEST, EXTR_IF_EXISTS )` provided that you define your variables beforehand?

Example:

```
$a = $b = $c = '';
extract( $_REQUEST, EXTR_IF_EXISTS );
```

or will this allow PHP globals and other sensitive things to be overwritten by a malicious attacker?

Comment: It looks ok to me... It will only set `$a, $b, and $c`, so as long as you clean those properly. @ITroubs has a good point.

Comment: I corrected my answer. Still extract is almost never the weapon of choice unless it is being used somewhere where it is being expected to be used like in the templatingsystem in kohana.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* do it, but you can just as easily avoid doing it:

```
$a = isset($_REQUEST['a']) ? $_REQUEST['a'] : '';
$b = isset($_REQUEST['b']) ? $_REQUEST['b'] : '';
$c = isset($_REQUEST['c']) ? $_REQUEST['c'] : '';
```

Then you can ensure nothing else is creeping into your current scope.

If you just want your code to be prettier, consider having a global helper function:

```
function request($k, $def=''){
    return isset($_REQUEST[$k]) ? $_REQUEST[$k] : $def;
}
```

And then you can just initialize as you want, with default values for unset args:

```
$a = request('a');
$b = request('b', null);
$c = request('c', "hello");
```

If you really want to use `extract`, try this:

```
function requested($a){
    return array_intersect_key($_REQUEST, array_flip($a));
}

extract( requested(array('a', 'b', 'c')), EXTR_IF_EXISTS );
```

This works by modifying `$_REQUEST` first to contain only the keys you want, then runs extract on it.

Comment: True. I'm trying to find a more elegant way to do it. It reads a lot nicer in the code. But obviously pretty but unsafe code = fail. Any suggestions?

Comment: Updated answer with a "prettier" solution.

Comment: Hey Cal. I like the last solution a lot. Possibly more than mine. Assuming you really don't care about the rest of $_REQUEST later on in your code, this is a very nice one indeed.

Comment: Since it doesn't actually *modify* `$_REQUEST` (just makes a copy of part of it), you can use it multiple times with different fields, all in one request.

Comment: Ah. I thought the first argument was by reference. I see that's not the case. Accepted. Thanks for sticking with it and giving it 2nd and 3rd try! :)

Answer (score 2):

Well it is not safe. Someone could do something like this: `www.example.com?_SERVER['anything']` or if he has any kind of knowledge he could try to inject something into another variable. It would still be some kind of a guessing game but it would be possible.

Also one typo in the name of one input could mess up your entire program when the extract is in the wrong place and replaces something that is important. Errors like that are very hard to debug.

Comment: Good points. It's a shame that you can't pass a template array to extract with ONLY the keys you wish to extract. Unless I missed something in the docs...

Comment: well actually you could do an array filter and with the use of a static class and an array in that static class you would even be able to filter an array and extract that array

Comment: Ha. THAT sounds like a lot of trouble for very little gains :)

Comment: This is pretty much what I was going to say, just with more examples. Pretty much any variable can be overwritten, including those outside of the function (`?GLOBALS[varname]=value`) and session (`?_SESSION[admin]=1&_SESSION[username]=admin`).

Comment: I think I just soiled myself, thinking of the possibilities. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

I think there's too much dubiousness with using `extract()` since you practically have to be in a local namespace in order to really know which variables have already been defined.

I'm going to go with something along these lines, which isn't quite as pretty, but is still fairly easy to see which variables are being accepted as inputs from `$_REQUEST`:

```
foreach ( array(
    'a',
    'b',
    'c',
    'foo' )
as $auth_var){
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST[$auth_var] ) ) ${$auth_var} = $_REQUEST[$auth_var];
}
```

### UPDATE

I'm digging Cal's solution better than mine. It looks nicer too:

```
extract ( array_intersect_key( $_REQUEST, array_flip( array(
    'a',
    'b',
    'c',
    'foo' )
) ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

That code does what you expect, but of course could go wrong if you put it in the wrong place:

```
include ('/some/file/with/super/secret/config/in.php');

$a = $b = $c = '';
extract( $_REQUEST, EXTR_IF_EXISTS );
```

But, as long as you know where you are doing it and what scope you are in, it will be fine.

Personally I probably wouldn't write this though, but then it depends on what you are trying to do.

If you are running on a server, remember that $_SERVER can be overwritten by this. In fact, short of trivial CLI apps, don't use this, it's too scary!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? You mean if the include that comes first also defines additional variables into that scope? In that case I suppose the $_REQUEST could clobber those variables.

Comment: Yeah, that's it, if you have a variable in the top file like `$admin = false`, then your extract could overwrite that – it's potentially a scary line of code to see. Unless it's very clear from its context (i.e. in a function/class with limited scope) which variables exist, I'd hesitate to use it.